# Can someone tell me vaguely how WhatRunsWhere works?

Tags: web-crawler, screen-scraping

WhatRunsWhere is offers 'competitive intelligence' for online media buying.  You can do things like find out which sites your competitors buy traffic from, find the ads with the highest impression share on a given network, search a network for relevant ad copy, and more. I want to, vaguely, understand how this works. I imagine there would be data mining involved, but does anyone have any more clues on how this would work?

I'm unable to find any (publically available) apis for these ad networks, which is why I'm puzzled.

The website is: whatrunswhere.com
adbeat.com offers a similar service

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say for sure, but I presume it is either by partnering with toolbars/plugins/apps data or more likely, just a very good web crawler. If you think about it, google images, in a sense, offers the same service.

Answer (score 0):

They send crawlers to top websites and click/check/parse the ad data.

Pretty shady since their "business" costs a lot to advertisers as a whole.

Just imagine you have put up an ad at the NY times, along comes a 'bot' who 'acts' like a user and clicks on your ad.

In one line - Doing their business at your cost.

Answer (score 0):

A competitive intelligence tool is like a spy who spots ads and landing pages of any advertiser. It also gives you a detailed view on used networks, keywords, targets, publishers and countries.

All this data is a ground point for building and running successful online campaigns, be it PPV or Display.

[BoxOfAds](https://www.boxofads.com)  is another option for a competitive intelligence tool.